# local address in java mission control

Tags: java, sockets, jmc

I'm using Java Mission Control to analyse a Java Flight Recorder recording.
I'm particularly focusing on the socket activity.
I'm able to see the remote address from which my application read data, or to which it writes data.
But I don't manage to see the local address used my application. More precisely I want to check the network card and the port used when my application open ports.
Is it possible to see this information in Java Mission Control?

Comment: The Socket I/O events currently don't record any information about the local port and address, although looking at the code it would probably be possible to add it. I can check with the people working with the JFR events if they have some other way of finding this out, or if they have some plan of adding the local info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket Read and Socket Write events only contain the remote address, and there is no way you can turn on the local address. There is an enhancement request for adding information about network interfaces in the Java bug database, but it's not targeted for a release.

Comment: could you mention the bug ID or the link to the enhancement request?